# Is it possible to disable android studio generating its own files?

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanted to know if its possible to disable the files android studio generates for example

"value v11" and more and also value's with translated strings and android's useless drawable and strings I didn't put in.

Comment: "android studio makes it's own strings and translations of that strings" -- no, it does not. Most likely, these are coming from libraries that you elected to include in your app. If you do not want those resources, get rid of the libraries. Beyond that, please provide a [mcve] demonstrating **exactly** what "files" that you think "android studio generates".

Comment: It generates useless strings and translators and also drawables i am using android studio's blank activity no librarys added after that.

Comment: Per your comments on the existing answer, your resources are coming from `appcompat-v7`. If you do not want the resources, remove `appcompat-v7` and the portions of your code that depend upon it (`AppCompatActivity`, `Theme.AppCompat` in your theme, `app:...` attributes in `menu` resources, etc.). You should also upgrade your Android Studio, as Android Studio 2.2.3 does not have a "Blank Activity" template. The "Empty Activity" template on Android Studio 2.2.x allows you to opt out of using `appcompat-v7`.

Comment: Well, My app wont work without that, I just want to disable the files its making.

Comment: You are welcome to experiment with [techniques for removing unused resources in `release` builds](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html#shrink-resources). However, unless you are fairly expert Android developer, or you have a very comprehensive test suite that you can run on your `release` build, you may run into problems if you try removing things that your code indirectly does actually need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those files are required. There is no way to disable that. And without them your app wont function properly (on all devices and api levels).

Comment: But can I disable the translations? It just weights my app too much.

Comment: yes translations you can disable. but not when creating project. You can go to strings.xml and mark them as translatable=false

Comment: I have no strings.xml android studio makes it's own strings and translations of that strings that I don't want :/

Comment: My string just has my app name.

Comment: But I have to decompile my APK and then delete it from the decompiled apk. I want it to disable that while generating signed apk. is it possible?

Comment: delete it before generating signed apk. If you are talking about the support library strings, those you cannot remove directly unless you use their source instead of dependencies

Comment: The Files generate after I generate my apk not inside android studio while the files arnt compiled. here is one of the string :     <string name="abc_action_bar_home_description">Navigate home</string>

Comment: Is there a way to disable it? It's annoying.

Comment: no direct way. one way is to remove the dependency and include the source of the libraries directly and them change the source as you want. Highly not recommended though.

Comment: Well, Will it be a smart move to remove the dependency?

Comment: I want my application to be slim, but the translations are taking like 1 MB+

Comment: Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: there is no way it can take 1mb+ check again

Comment: It does, my app only has mainacitivty with 2 public voids, the drawables it generates (icons) and values total up 1 MB